# SSIS Dynamic schema mapping from source to destination

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

I want to create a dynamic  SSIS package which will first check if is there any schema change in the source? if yes then alter the destination accordingly( not drop and then create a table) and then made a data transfer.
I have tried using the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task, but this option drops the table first. 
Can anyone help me with this, Thanks in advance.

My Script -

```
 public string CompareDDL(DataRowCollection sourceArray, DataRowCollection destArray)
    {
        var upQuery = "";
        var source = "";
        var sourcetype = "";
        var TableColumns = "";
        if (destArray.Count == 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.Count; i++)
            {
                var sourceItem = sourceArray[i].ItemArray;
                source = sourceItem[1] + "." + sourceItem[2];
                TableColumns += "[" + sourceItem[3] + "] " + getDataType(sourceItem) + ",";
            }
            upQuery = "Create table " + source + " (" + TableColumns.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
        }
        else if (sourceArray.Count > destArray.Count)
        {
            for (var i = destArray.Count; i < sourceArray.Count; i++)
            {
                var sourceItem = sourceArray[i].ItemArray;
                sourcetype += sourceItem[3] + " " + getDataType(sourceItem) + ",";
                source = sourceItem[1] + "." + sourceItem[2];

            }
            upQuery = "ALTER TABLE " + source + " ADD " + sourcetype.TrimEnd(',');

        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.Count; i++)
            {
                var sourceItem = sourceArray[i].ItemArray;
                var destItem = destArray[i].ItemArray;
                if (sourceItem[5].ToString() == destItem[5].ToString())
                {
                    if (sourceItem[6].ToString() == destItem[6].ToString())
                    {
                        if (sourceItem[0].ToString() == destItem[9].ToString())
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        upQuery += "ALTER TABLE " + sourceItem[1] + "." + sourceItem[2] + " ALTER COLUMN " + sourceItem[3] + " " + getDataType(sourceItem);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    upQuery += "ALTER TABLE " + sourceItem[1] + "." + sourceItem[2] + " ALTER COLUMN " + sourceItem[3] + " " + getDataType(sourceItem);
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }

        return upQuery;
    }

    public string getDataType(object[] array)
    {
        string dataType = array[5].ToString();

        if (dataType.ToLower() == "int" || dataType.ToLower() == "date")
        {
            return dataType;
        }
        else if (dataType.ToLower().Contains("char"))
        {
            return array[5].ToString() + " (" + array[7].ToString() + ")";
        }
        else if (dataType.ToLower() == "decimal")
        {
            return array[5].ToString() + " (" + array[6].ToString() + " ," + array[9].ToString() + ")";
        }

        return dataType;
    }

    public DataTable getDestination(SqlConnection DestinationConnection)
    {
        //Destinantion
        //Read list of Tables with Schema from Database
        string dQuery = "SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, NUMERIC_PRECISION, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE,DATETIME_PRECISION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE        TABLE_NAME = 'Inventory'";

        //MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand(dQuery, DestinationConnection);
        DestinationConnection.Open();
        DataTable ddt = new DataTable();
        ddt.Load(dCmd.ExecuteReader());
        DestinationConnection.Close();
        return ddt;
    }
    public DataTable getSource(SqlConnection myADONETConnection)
    {
        //Destinantion
        //Read list of Tables with Schema from Database
        string query = "SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, NUMERIC_PRECISION, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE,DATETIME_PRECISION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE        TABLE_NAME = 'Inventory'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        myADONETConnection.Close();

        return dt;

    }

    public object getInsertQueryParam(object a)
    {
        string re = null;
        //  string dataType = array[5].ToString();

        if (a.GetType() == typeof(int) || a.GetType() == typeof(decimal) || a.GetType().ToString().Contains("date"))
        {
            return a;
        }
        else if (a.GetType() == typeof(DBNull))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return "'" + a + "'";
        }

    }


    public void getDestinationTableSchema()
    {
        //Source
        SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections[Dts.Variables["User::SourceLocal"].Value.ToString()].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

        //Destinantion 
        SqlConnection DestinationConnection = new SqlConnection(Dts.Variables["User::SourceLocal"].Value.ToString());

        DataTable dt = getSource(myADONETConnection);
        DataTable ddt = getDestination(DestinationConnection);


        var upQuery = CompareDDL(dt.Rows, ddt.Rows);

        if (upQuery != "")
        {
            DestinationConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(upQuery, DestinationConnection);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DestinationConnection.Close();
            ddt = getDestination(DestinationConnection);
            upQuery = CompareDDL(dt.Rows, ddt.Rows);
        }

        string SchemaName = "";
        string DbName = "";
        string TableName = "";
        string TableColumns = "";
        foreach (DataRow dt_row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string ColumnName = "";
            string ColumnType = "";
            string ColumnIsNull = "";
            object[] array = dt_row.ItemArray;
            SchemaName = array[1].ToString();
            TableName = array[2].ToString();
            ColumnName = array[3].ToString();
            ColumnType = getDataType(array);
            ColumnIsNull = array[0].ToString();
            DbName = array[0].ToString();
        }

        string queryString = "SELECT * from " + SchemaName + "." + TableName;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        var command = "";
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            String sqlCommandInsert = "";
            String sqlCommandValue = "";
            var dindex = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
            {
                sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                dindex++;
            }
            sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
            sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);



            sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into [" + SchemaName + "].[" + TableName + "] (" + sqlCommandValue + ") VALUES";

            int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
            var inQuery = "";
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                string columnvalues = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                    columnvalues += getInsertQueryParam(table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i]) + ",";

                }
                inQuery += "( "+ columnvalues.TrimEnd(',') + "),";


            }
            command = sqlCommandInsert + inQuery.TrimEnd(',');


        }
        myADONETConnection.Close();
        var finalQuery = "";
        if (upQuery == "")
        {
            finalQuery = command;
        }
        else
        {
            finalQuery = upQuery + " " + command;
        }

        DestinationConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(finalQuery, DestinationConnection);
        myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DestinationConnection.Close();


    }

    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {
            getDestinationTableSchema();
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
            Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

            }

        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: SSIS is not designed for dynamic data flows in general. Defining data with meta data is extremely strict. If schema change is just column order than name your columns in your extract. You should also show what you have tried.

Comment: Hi KeithL, I have added my approach above.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script task to do this.